# SpinBoxStyle unable to access button state

Tags: qt, qml

`SpinBoxStyle` from `QtQuick.Controls.Styles` allows you to change the appearance of a `SpinBox`, and a part of that is the ability to redesign the up/down arrow buttons.  However neither `SpinBox` nor the style gives you the ability to query the up/down arrow button state, so you can't check if it is pressed or hovered over.

This seems like too much of an oversight, so what part of the API docs have I missed?

I've tried adding a `MouseArea` to the control delegate itself, but some reason it never receives any events - the controls still work though which suggests that they are 'stealing' the events first.

```
SpinBox {
    style: SpinBoxStyle {
        incrementControl: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: 10
            implicitWidth: 10
            color: "blue"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true

                onEntered: console.log( "Hello" ) // Never printed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking out for http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-spinbox.html#hovered-prop

Comment: That is for hovering over the entire control.  I've tried putting a `MouseArea` within my control delegate and picking up events from that, but it never fires - plus that feels hackish.  I'll add the code to my question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/1aecda36d1d12bcd24a5ee87dd82ed04f85c41e2:src/controls/SpinBox.qml#L205) you're supposed to use the styleData properties to detect hovered and pressed states, but they aren't documented. Please create a bug report for that.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

SpinBox {
    style: SpinBoxStyle {
        incrementControl: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: 10
            implicitWidth: 10
            color: styleData.upHovered && !styleData.upPressed
                ? Qt.lighter("blue") : (styleData.upPressed ? Qt.darker("blue") : "blue")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the style was implemented this way, but if you look further into the source code, you can see that there are always `MouseArea`s for the up and down controls. This is very confusing to me; if you're not supposed to provide an interactive control because there will always be `MouseArea`s shadowing them, why call it `incrementControl` and `decrementControl`? Names like `increment` and `decrement` might suffice, given that they're not able to receive almost any interaction (clicking works at least, for some reason). If you find this a bit confusing, you may also want to file a separate bug report for the API.

`git log --follow -p` shows that this code hasn't changed much since the introduction of styles, so I'd say the current implementation (and API) is just outdated, and hopefully there are opportunities for improving this in the future.

Comment: Ah ha! I did think that it was odd that I used a `styleData` object in `MenuStyle`, but the docs for `SpinBox` didn't mention it.  I looked at the source code before I posted the question, but I just disregarded the `__styleData` due to the preceding underscores.  I'll create a bug report now.  Thanks!

Comment: Bug logged here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-41634 for those wishing to follow.